# Let $\gamma $ be an ordinal. Prove there is an ordering preserving $f:\gamma \to \mathbb{R}$ iff $\gamma < \omega_1.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Let $<$ be the usual ordering on $\mathbb{R}.$ If $\gamma$ is an ordinal, then $f:\gamma \to \mathbb{R}$ is ordering preserving if $\forall \alpha \in\gamma \forall \beta \in \gamma [\alpha \in \beta \implies f(\alpha) < f(\beta)].$

Let $\gamma $ be an ordinal. Prove there is an ordering preserving $f:\gamma \to \mathbb{R}$ iff $\gamma < \omega_1.$

Could anyone advise on this problem?

Given $\exists$ order-preserving $f: \gamma \to \mathbb{R},$ suppose $\gamma \geq \omega_1.$ We know that there is a rational number between any two real numbers, so how I derive a contradiction from here?

Comment: Some older questions related to this: [Formal proof for A subset of the real numbers, well ordered with the normal order of $\mathbb R$, is at most $\aleph_0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44559/),
[Embedding ordinals in $\mathbb Q$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123969/embedding-ordinals-in-mathbbq) and
[Countable ordinals are embeddable in the rationals $\mathbb Q$ — proofs and their use of AC](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408300/countable-ordinals-are-embeddable-in-the-rationals-bbb-q-proofs-and-their).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** If $f : \omega_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ is order preserving, consider the following family of open intervals: $$\{ (\; f ( \alpha ) , f ( \alpha + 1 )\; ) : \alpha \in \omega_1 \}.$$  (Recall that $\mathbb{R}$ is separable.)

Given $\gamma < \omega_1$, to construct an order-preserving function $f : \gamma \to \mathbb{R}$ it is easier to proceed by induction on $\gamma$, and moreover show that such an $f$ can be taken to have bounded range (*i.e.*, $|f(\alpha)| \leq M$ for all $\alpha \in \gamma$ for some $M \in \mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Thank you! For the 1st part, instead of proving by contradiction, could we let $X =\{ (\; f ( \alpha ) , f ( \alpha + 1 )\; ) : \alpha \in \gamma \}$ and define function $F: X \to \mathbb{Q}$ by $F(A) = \frac{\left \lfloor {f(\alpha)} \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor {f(\alpha +1)} \right \rfloor}{2},$ where $A = (f(\alpha), f(\alpha + 1)) \in X.$ Then $|X| \leq \omega$ and hence $\gamma \leq \omega ?$

Comment: @Alexy: You proposed idea would not work, since we haven't ruled out the possibility that the function $\alpha \mapsto \lfloor f(\alpha) \rfloor$ is constant.  (What if $0 \leq f(\alpha) < 1$ for all $\alpha$?)

Comment: Thank you for the correction. May I trouble you to elaborate on why would it work for $\gamma \geq \omega_1? $

Comment: Can we consider $\{ (\; f ( \alpha ) , f ( \alpha + 1 )\; ) : \alpha \in \gamma \}$ and given $(f(\alpha), f(\alpha + 1)),$ choose a rational $r_ {\alpha} \in (f(\alpha), f(\alpha + 1))?$ Now, define $F:\{ (\; f ( \alpha ) , f ( \alpha + 1 )\; ) : \alpha \in \gamma \} \to \mathbb{Q}$ by $F(A) = r_{\alpha},$ where $A=(f(\alpha), f(\alpha + 1)).$ Then, $|\{ (\; f ( \alpha ) , f ( \alpha + 1 )\; ) : \alpha \in \gamma \}| \leq \omega? $

Comment: @Alexy: As soon as there is no order preserving function $\omega_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ there cannot be an order preserving function $\gamma \to \mathbb{R}$ for any $\gamma > \omega_1$ (since such an order preserving function restricted to $\omega_1$ would give an order preserving function $\omega_1 \to \mathbb{R}$).  But you are correct, the same argument will apply to any $\gamma > \omega_1$.

Comment: Sir, thank you for the advice. But I have not assumed $\gamma \geq \omega_1$ and if so, would my proposed proof still work? ( see the my comment just before your latest reply).

Comment: @Alexy: Your proof only shows that ***if*** there is an order-preserving function $f : \gamma \to \mathbb{R}$, then $\gamma < \omega_1$.  In order to show the opposite direction you will need to show that for each $\gamma < \omega_1$ ***there is*** an order preserving function $f : \gamma \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I'm actually referring to the "if" part of the statement. Anyways, thanks for your instruction.